# vscode navigate search editor using keyboard only

Tags: search, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to navigate the search editor (whole workspace search) using only cursor keys in vscode ?  I'm talking about the whole workspace search and not just the find/replace search.[image: This is the editor I'm talking about]

Comment: Can you include a picture or some sort of visual descriptor because vscode has multiple search ‘editors’. Either way you should be above to navigate tabbing through the elements, or forcing tab trapping mode  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility#_tab-navigation

Comment: included an image.

Comment: Please mark my answer accepted if it helped pandith, otherwise let me know where I can improve

Comment: For reference: Search Editor [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-editor) ([snap](https://archive.ph/rBE0b#_search-editor) [shots](https://web.archive.org/web/20230308202759/https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-editor)) and release notes of [v1.43](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_43) from February 2020.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The new search editor thankfully has ported over most of the shortcut commands you have grown to know, but for brevity, this answer will include only the default keybinds with respective command id.

The `when` expression most commonly associated with these keybinds, should you want to alter them, are :

`inSearchEditor`

`hasSearchResult`

`searchInputBoxFocus`

## Searching

**Context Lines**

- Toggle context lines : `toggleSearchEditorContextLines` <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

  > Will show n lines before or after search result, for context
- Reduce context line quantity : `decreaseSearchEditorContextLines` <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>
- Increase context line quantity : `increaseSearchEditorContextLines` <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>

**Query Details**

- Toggle Query Details : `workbench.action.search.toggleQueryDetails`

  > This will toggle the include/exclude file input boxes

**Settings**

- Toggle Match Case : `toggleSearchCaseSensitive` <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- Toggle Regex : `toggleSearchEditorRegex` <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Toggle Word Match : `toggleSearchEditorWholeWord` <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

## Navigation

Luckily, because the search editor is effectively an 'editor', you can continue to use all the keybinds that you are used to. So, in order to jump straight to the editor, you can use whatever your keybind is to jump to an editor group, default is: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (commandId: `workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup`)

**Navigating matches**

- Go to next match : `search.action.focusNextSearchResult` <kbd>F4</kbd>
- Go to previous match : `search.action.focusPreviousSearchResult` <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>
- Select all matches : `selectAllSearchEditorMatches` <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

**Results**

- Deleting result block : `workbench.action.searchEditor.deleteResultBlock` <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>

  > This deletes a block of results from the editor

  For example, in the picture below, if my cursor is anywhere in the 'convert.js' result block the entire convert.js matches would be removed. You can undo this with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>
- Go To Definition (effectively go to file)

  - You can peek with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> when your cursor is *anywhere on the file name*
  - You can assign a keyboard shortcut to follow links for the commandId: `editor.action.openLink` for when your cursor is on the file name
  - You can go directly to the file & line number of the search result using <kbd>F12</kbd> while your cursor is anywhere on that result

**Navigate Back to Input Box**

- Focus Search Input Box From Results: `search.action.focusQueryEditorWidget` <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd>

## Searching within Search Editor

As noted, the search editor is effectively an editor, so you can resume using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (find) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (find/replace) to narrow down results even more, and the keybinds set for those are maintained as used elsewhere.

[image: search editor]

## Miscellaneous

- Search again: `rerunSearchEditorSearch` <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

  > Perhaps you deleted too many result blocks

Otherwise, while your cursor is actively in the editor (results), you have the freedom to use *most* of your keybinds per normal, including collapsing/folding, jumping, copying, moving to editor groups etc

Comment: With VSCode 1.51: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107208, one more shortcut.